# Errors: expected ';' after expression and expression result unused

Tags: c, cs50

Why am I getting the errors of `"expected ';' after expression`, and `expressions result unused`?  Here is my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   printf("How tall do you want your pyramid to be?\n");
   int height = GetInt();

   if (height > 23 && height < 1)
   {
       printf("Please use a positive number no greater than 23:\n");
   }
   else (height > 0 && height <= 23)
   {
       printf("Thanks!\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: you want `else if` instead of `else`. or delete `(height > 0 && height <= 23)`. also `height > 23 && height < 1` --> `height > 23 || height < 1`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: why don't you post that as answer?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis this is typo question.

Comment: I'm not sure it is typo. Looks like unfamiliarity with the language to me.

Comment: It's not all typo, it is logical, see first condition, and there needs not even be a second test, just an `else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such things as

```
else (height > 0 && height <= 23)
```

else means everything else, so you can't give else a condition.
Use else if instead ^^

Answer (score 4):

You are getting this error because you cannot give a condition check with `else`. You probably want to use `else if`

But, one thing you will notice is that both the condition is globally exhaustive, so you do not need an `else if` check with a condition. Just an `else` without any condition check will do the job for you.

---

Plus, according to the condition check that you have given, it will never be true. Since, `height` cannot be greater then `23` and lower then `1` both at the same time. What you need is an or `||` check instead of an and `&&`

So, your code would become

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   printf("How tall do you want your pyramid to be?\n");
   int height = GetInt();

   if (height > 23 || height < 1)
   {
       printf("Please use a positive number no greater than 23:\n");
   }
   else
   {
       printf("Thanks!\n");
   }
}
```